# Three linear expressions of three unknowns equal to each other, get right answer by solving each expression equal to zero: does this hold in general?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I have three linear expressions that are equal:

$$
a_1x+b_1y+c_1z + d_1 = a_2x+b_2y+c_2z + d_2 = a_3x+b_3y+c_3z + d_3
$$

I set each expression equal to zero (not sure why) and then solved the resulting system, and that yielded the correct answer.

$$
a_1x+b_1y+c_1z = -d_1\\
a_2x+b_2y+c_2z = -d_2\\
a_3x+b_3y+c_3z = -d_3
$$

Did I just happen to luck into the right answer because of the particulars of my system of equations, or would this hold in general?

Comment: If $x+y=2x+y$, you get the line $x=0$ as the solution. However, if $x+y=0$ and $2x+y=0$, you get only $x=y=0$ as the solution. There's no explanation for what you did and it is not correct. The original equations give you two independent equations, and the solution set is expected to be a line. When you set each equal to $0$, you get three (generally) independent equations and the solution is just a point. Perhaps you should edit your question with the precise question/solution you have.

Answer (score 1):

Without the assumption that they are all equal to $0$, you get

$$
a_1x+b_1y+c_1z = -d_1 + k\\
a_2x+b_2y+c_2z = -d_2 + k\\
a_3x+b_3y+c_3z = -d_3 + k
$$

where $k$ is an additional (unknown) constant.

One explanation as to why you (still) got the right answer is that in your subsequent algebraic manipulations, the $k$ variables in each equation canceled each other out.

Unclear if this is actually what happened.

Comment: For each value of $k$ you expect to get a single (point) solution, and then as $k$ varies, these points string together and form a line, as we expect.

Comment: @TedShifrin Nice filling of the gap.  I was forced to write in generalities because the OP (i.e. original poster) was **vague** about what subsequent manipulations that they used.  The OP was also vague about what constitutes the *right answer*.

Comment: Indeed. Note that I asked the OP to edit with the precise question/solution.